# Can't connect to MySQL from Spring-Boot container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker-compose

I'm trying to connect my Spring-Boot application (one container) to a MySQL database (another container). I have following error while starting my Java app:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Here is my [docker-compose.yml](https://gist.github.com/smolamarcin/3bef6149b851f7db874fd48c8828390c):

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=family
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=family_db
      - MYSQL_USER=family_user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=family
    ports:
      - 9999:3306
  web:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile-spring
      image: family:latest
      depends_on:
        - db
      ports:
        - 0:8080
      environment:
#        - DATABASE_HOST=db
        - DATABASE_USER=family_user
        - DATABASE_PASSWORD=family
        - DATABASE_NAME=family_db
        - DATABASE_PORT=3306
#        - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/family_db?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
#        - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/test?useSSL=false
#        - spring.datasource.username=family_user
#        - spring.datasource.password=family
#        - spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

  angular:
    container_name: angular-container
    build: 
      context: angular-app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-angular
    ports:
      - 0:80
```

Here is my Dockerfile-spring:

```
FROM openjdk:8
VOLUME /tmp<br> COPY target/family.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","app.jar"]
```

What should I do to open the MySQL port for my Spring-Boot application?

Comment: Try changing `DATABASE_PORT=3306` to `DATABASE_PORT=9999`, because that's the port you expose on your other container

Comment: When I'm changing port to 9999, spring boot throws exception about unknown driver class. I have mysql driver added in my pom. I though that I have to connect on port 3306 which lvies inside Docker.

Comment: If you're setting driver class via an environment variable (as it seems you are) then try using SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME

Comment: I've added different application properties for profiles in spring boot. When I changed the name of the username to 'root 'in production app properties it sometimes works, sometimes not. I don't know what to do. Exception about driver disappeared, because it's specified in properties file.

Comment: I've just updated docker-compose.yml to

Comment: I've tried everything. My mysql container is running. I can reach it from my MySQL workbench, but still can't connect from spring boot app. Still I have an error: The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create own network for docker using bridge driver.

Comment: Could you pls make it more specific and explain why?

Comment: Docker compose by default should make all containers reachable by other containers, but in my case it does not work. One solution should be to link containers to each other, but this solution is deprecated. The proper solution is to define own network. Here's the example and all is explained: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks.<br> Another issue with my code was wrong ip in spring boot, because it should look something like this: jdbc:mysql://db:3306/family_db?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false, where db is name of the docker service defined in docker-compose.yml